# Create Quadrilateral frustum out of 8 points in 3D

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I've the following question:
Given a set of 8 unique points in 3D I need to create a quadrilateral frustrum
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron#/media/File:Usech_kvadrat_piramid.png).
By this I mean I need calculate the faces of the quadrilateral frustrum.

My first idea was to calculate the convex hull of the point set, this should
give me the faces which I need. I think this should work, but probably there is
a much better way to do this.

[image: 8 points, need to find the quadrilateral faces]

Thanks for your time.

Best,
S.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _calculating the convex hull_? In two dimensions, there are various algorithms to calculate the _convex hull polygon_, is there something similar for three dimensions? I imagine some kind of modified Simplex algorithm.

Comment: Yes, there are convex hull algorithms for 3d point clouds.

Comment: do you have any further constraints for the to-be-calculated frustum? You can easily calculate *a* frustum, which includes a given set of points -- but maybe you want one with minimal volume/surface or with some constraints on the orientation?

Comment: E.g., a rectangular cuboid is a special case of a quadrilateral frustum, and you can calculate that by just taking the minimal and maximal x,y,z-coordinates.

Comment: @chtz: I added a figure. I have the displayed points above, and i need to find 6 quadrilateral faces basically. I have to do this programmatically because the points in my set can change and I don't know them a-priori.

Btw.: The frustrum should not be degenerated, i.e. the 6 faces should not intersect respectively twist into each other.

Comment: So you got 8 points, which you know are the corners of your frustum, but you don't know their order?

Comment: Yes that's the case.

Comment: You can just brute-force all combinations of 4 vertices and check if they are co-planar. Maybe start by generating a minimum spanning tree and check the first 4 connected corners if they are co-planar (I assume they always should be, unless you almost have a regular cube)

Comment: @chtz: that might be a starting point. however I know that the 8 points should be the corners of the frustrum. however, they are allowed to be slightly not co-planar.

In the end I need a frustrum which has co-planar faces of course. So actually I might need to move one of the vertices, such that I get a co-planar face I guess.